# why is my PHP page not querying the database properly?

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I am trying to set up a script that queries a database to populate a page.  This is my first foray into database querying in PHP, so forgive me if the problem is something really stupid.

The problem I have is that the page does not seem to connect to the database, as the first 2 debug statements are rendered in the browser, but nothing after them is.  however, when I run it on the command line using php.exe, it runs properly and displays all required data from the query.

I am running wampserver 2.2 on windows 7 and it does not display in any browser (tested in Chrome, Firefox, and IE9.

My current code is below.  I have also tried moving the connection to the head, but that prevents anything, even debug1, from rendering.  The die statement is not rendered in any circumstance.

```
<html>

<body>   
debug1<br /> 

<?php
echo "debug2<br />";
$con = mysql_connect("hostname.of.database","username","password") die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
echo "debug3<br />";

mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Mail");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['Sender'];
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row['Subject'];
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row['Message'];
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<br />";
  }

echo "debug4<br />";

mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

After moving the `die` statement to the same line as the connection, I get the following rendered in the page:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 10
```

**EDIT**

I have added `extension=php_mysql.dll` to my php.ini file and restarted the servers.  I am now getting the following page:

[image: error messages]

**EDIT**

Problem solved.  My last problem was that I forgot to replace `hostname.of.database` with the actual hostname.

For those who read this in the future, the solution is as follows:

1. don't close the connection before retrieving the results
2. ensure that the php_mysql extension is enabled by adding `extension=php_mysql.dll` to the php.ini file
3. reboot the server, clear the browser cache and try again.

Comment: You closed the connection too soon.  the mysql_fetch_array() function needs the connection to still be open.

Comment: Check your error log for more details, or put this at the top of the script: `ini_set("display_errors", true);` - this should give you more information for this and other issues.

Comment: I'd suggest investing time into learning how to use mysqli before you get comfortable using the `mysql_query` APIs, which are insecure and being deprecated in PHP6.

Comment: Your fatal error would suggest that the PHP mysql extension is not loaded from your php.ini.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're closing the connection before fetching results:

```
// Don't do this!!!
//mysql_close($con);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['Sender'];
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row['Subject'];
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row['Message'];
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

Unless you specifically have a need to free some memory or destroy a connection when you intend to create another one, it is usually not necessary to make explicit calls to `mysql_close()`. It will be called when the script completes execution.

#### Update:

After posting your error message, it would appear that the MySQL extension is not enabled for your WAMP stack. A different php.ini file may be used by the command line than is used by the web server.  Locate the correct php.ini by calling `phpinfo()` and enable the MySQL extension.

Comment: this did not solve the problem.  it still does not render beyond the second debug statement.

Comment: @ewok Then you have some other issue that will turn up when you set `display_errors` on. Perhaps bad database permissions on `dbname`.

Comment: how do I check if the mysql extension is enabled in the php.ini file?  according to the wamp tray icon, mysql is selected.  I tried restarting the services, but it did not help

Comment: @ewok On Windows, `extension=php_mysql.dll ` is what you need, I believe.

Comment: @ewok Place the function `phpinfo();` into a web page and run it. It will display all the enabled extensions plus tons of other information.

Comment: I added that line, but it did not help. where in `phpinfo()` will it show the enabled extensions?

Comment: @ewok Be sure to restart the web server after enabling the extension. In the phpinfo() output, extensions are listed each with their own headings followed by a table of information. Basically everything after the apache environment & core relates to extensions.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of recommendations before you could move on -

1. Enable error messages by setting `ini_set('display_errors','On');` AND `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
2. After trying to connect to the database, make sure the connection was successful and output the error otherwise, which will help you spot the issue, as follows:

```php
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
```

Shai.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to turn on php error reporting for more detailed error messages:

```
<?php ini_set(‘display_errors’,1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ?>
```

You can read more about it here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php